# Loading bundle specific values for dev, prod and test environment

Tags: symfony

The documentation mentiones `Symfony/app/config/config_dev.yml` for dev environment.

I have bundle specific config files that are loaded with `Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/DependencyInjection/mmtmrExtension.php`

For example: `Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` needs to be loaded by `mmtmrExtension.php` but `routing.yml` in the same directory doesn't.

Is there a naming convention I have to follow? Then how do I load `Symfony/src/mmt/mrBundle/Resources/config/services_dev.yml` based on environment in `mmtmrExtension.php`? The only examples I've seen is just hard code load the `services.yml` ant that's it.

In `services.yml` I have some code like:

```
mmt.mr.DefaultController:
     class: mmt\mrBundle\Controller\DefaultController
     arguments: [@data_provider]
     calls: 
         - [ "setContainer", [ @service_container ] ]
```

Maybe I should have different services loaded here based on environment? I would like another `@data_provider` used.

There seems to be a hundreds ways of doing this but none of them are 100% covered by the documentation. I'd rather have one way of doing it but have 100% document coverage.

Maybe someone can point me to the right place how config files work. "The Book" doesn't cover much and cook book only mentions the parts that are relevant to "how do I" stuff.

Thank you for reading this and hope you can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This must do the trick:

```
    //src/Acme/DemoBundle/DepedencyInjection/AcmeDemoExtension.php

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    switch ($container->getParameter('kernel.environment')) {
        case 'dev':
            $loader->load('services_dev.yml');
            break;
        case 'prod':
            $loader->load('services_prod.yml');
            break;
        case 'test':
            $loader->load('services_test.yml');
            break;
        default:
            $loader->load('services_dev.yml');
            break;
    }
```

Comment: This is the right way, but I would prefer to remove the switch case.

Comment: The adventage of switch case is it's never thrown exception, have you a better solution ?

Comment: Jep, let it crash. A configuration file is a core file in my eyes, so no check is needed I expect that. if the file doesn't exist your whole application will crash. Its better to let it crash instead to load implicit an other configuration file, this can end in undefined behavior. And it the service_dev.yml doesn't exist an error occurs. But it depends on your needs.
PS: All Symfony FileLoader / Locator have its own exception handling.

Comment: I agree, the default switch clause is a bad idea. After that, using "if", "switch" or concatenation is at your convenance.

Comment: Surely something like this would do everything you need
`$loader->load("services_{$container->getParameter('kernel.environment')}.yml");`